# env-var npm package working in some part of the codebase, but not everywhere (Nestjs)

Tags: node.js, typescript, environment-variables, nestjs

I am facing a weird issue. I am using [env-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-var) package for managing the environnement variables in a NestJs project.

I have also installed the `@nestjs/config` as per that [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration). Hence the following code:
`src/app.module.ts`

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      autoSchemaFile: 'schema.gql',
    }),
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(config.db),
    ExerciseModule,
    ProgramModule,
    WorkoutModule,
    AthleteModule,
    AuthModule,
    BiometricsModule,
    DailyTaskModule,
    PerformanceModule,
    SessionModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I replaced the hardcoded JWT secret for the env var in `src/auth/jwt.strategy.ts` as such:

```
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt'
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport'
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import * as env from 'env-var'

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: env.get('JWT_SECRET').required().asString(),
    })
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return { athleteId: payload.athleteId }
  }
}
```

and that's working fine.

But if I use the same code in `src/auth/auth.module.ts`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { AuthResolver } from './auth.resolver'
import { AuthService } from './auth.service'
import { getRepositoryToken, TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
import { TypeOrmAthleteRepository } from '../athlete/repositories/typeorm-athlete.repository'
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt'
import { EmailGatewayToken } from './gateways/email.gateway'
import { InMemoryEmailGateway } from './gateways/in-memory-email.gateway'
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport'
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy'
import { APP_GUARD } from '@nestjs/core'
import { GqlAuthGuard } from './gql.auth.guard'
import { ATHLETE_REPOSITORY } from '../athlete/repositories/athlete-repository.interface'
import * as env from 'env-var'

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([TypeOrmAthleteRepository]),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: env.get('JWT_SECRET').required().asString(),
      signOptions: { expiresIn: 3600 * 24 },
    }),
    PassportModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: EmailGatewayToken, useClass: InMemoryEmailGateway },
    {
      provide: ATHLETE_REPOSITORY,
      useExisting: getRepositoryToken(TypeOrmAthleteRepository),
    },
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: GqlAuthGuard,
    },
    JwtStrategy,
    AuthResolver,
    AuthService,
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Now I can't compile the project, I face this error:

```
➜  back git:(feature/use-real-token-after-login) ✗ yarn start:dev
yarn run v1.22.17
$ nest start --watch
[2:01:43 PM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

[2:01:47 PM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.


/Users/arthurmehmetoglu/Development/corpo-sano-2/back/node_modules/env-var/lib/variable.js:47
    throw new EnvVarError(errMsg)
          ^
EnvVarError: env-var: "JWT_SECRET" is a required variable, but it was not set
    at raiseError (/Users/arthurmehmetoglu/Development/corpo-sano-2/back/node_modules/env-var/lib/variable.js:47:11)
    at Object.asString (/Users/arthurmehmetoglu/Development/corpo-sano-2/back/node_modules/env-var/lib/variable.js:64:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/arthurmehmetoglu/Development/corpo-sano-2/back/src/auth/auth.module.ts:21:48)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/arthurmehmetoglu/Development/corpo-sano-2/back/src/program/program.module.ts:6:1)
```

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `env-var` reads from `process.env` by default. Nest ends up calling`dotenv`'s `parse` method and populating `process.env` inside of the `forRoot()` method, but that does not happen immediately. All code inside of decorators (including `@Module()`) is called at the time of file import, so what's happening here is that you're trying to access `prcoess.env.JWT_SECRET` before it is populated. One option would be to make the `register` a `registerAsync` and give it a dependency on the `ConfigService` to ensure that the `process.env` has been populated before trying to read `env.get('JWT_SECRET')`.

This works inside of the constructor, by the way, because that's at a later time once Nest has populated the `process.env`.

Another option would be to forgo Nest's `ConfigModule` and add `import 'dotenv/config'` as **the first line** of your `main.ts` file, so that you just leave populating the `process.env` object to `dotenv` and don't use Nest's `ConfigService` as an injectable.

Comment: I went for what seems to be the simpler options: the import of dotenv in the `main.ts` file. It works like a charm, thanks!

For the record, I also needed to add it on the first line of my e2e tests.